# What is Next.js in the context of React?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am new to React and came across **Next.js**. Being new to React, beyond a general understanding that it's a software tool used many React programmers and projects I couldn't figure out and what specific problems of React development it helps address.

Could someone explain? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

long story short , if we simplify it there's two types of web applications "SSR & SPA"

**SPA( Single Page Application)** : which you are using in your regular react.js , the backend provide APIs for you & you change the DOM with it , so you render the page at the client side the server just provide you with the information you need throw APIs

**SSR( server side render)**: when you use for example "Node.js" as aback end you can send the page to the Client side renderd already with something  called Template engines using **NEXT.js** one of them for example " of course there's alot of lib used for this purpose too  like you can see it here [https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html"](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/template-engines.html%22)  and it just present it to the user "UI" ,of course this cost the server some time and that's why people started using **SPA**

Both of them are correct , but it depends on your application needs "speed - security..etc"

and this is the Next.js Doc start you can check it for your first App
https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app

Comment: Also, SSR and SPA aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: I see, thanks for the answer! Can you use Next.js with any backend? Also @ZacharyHaber

Comment: as far as i know any backend uses template engine it can use it

Comment: @AlyAbdElRahman Ok, I will mark it as answer, but do you know the benefits of using it vs. not using it? When would it make sense to use Next? Thank you SO much!!!

Comment: it depends on the application business if you need more security " transactional - payments -..etc" people are most likely to use SSR which can be done with many languages and the frontend for them or the template engine can be Next.js for example , therefore there's no exact rule for it  , but most people preferer to use Next.js with Node.js application , but of course it's not a must